# Implementation of Rate & Review Option for an App in windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, rating

How could i implement the "Rate Us" Options inside the app?

Anyone help out to solve this?

Comment: Use [`MarketplaceReviewTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.marketplacereviewtask(v=vs.105).aspx) to launch the store/marketplace and then display the review page for the current app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this ...

```
MarketplaceReviewTask marketplaceReviewTask = new MarketplaceReviewTask();
marketplaceReviewTask.Show();
```

I hope this will work for u ....

Comment: Oh. I have one doubt that markerplaceReviewTask.Show();
will get the link to review page of the current running app. Is that Right?

Comment: if you think its correct answer you can give tick to the answer so that it will help others